# How to sign my commits to Github repository where I am not the owner?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, gnupg, sign

I am trying to sign my commits in all Github repositories I am associated with. I can sign when the repository is hosted by me, but can not able to sign when I am just a contributor. I get this error mentioned below every time I try to do so.

```
could not find identity matching specified user-id: <key id>
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

below is my .gitconfig setup

```
[core]
        editor = \"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Cod>
[user]
        email = <my email id>
        name = <my name>
        signingkey = <key id>
[commit]
        gpgsign = false
[gpg]
        program = gpg
```

Your small help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear the git cache or delete the repo from your pc and re-clone it and try to sign your next commits. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Github has nothing to do with what you sign on your local copy of a repository. From the error message, I assume you didn't provide a key id, so git used your committer identity, which doesn't have a corresponding key in the gpg keystore. Perhaps the `user.name` and `user.email` configuration values are not set up correctly.

- You can check the values and if the global config isn't accidentally overridden by local settings with:

  ```
  git config --show-origin user.name
  git config --show-origin user.email
  ```

  The values should match with a key in the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`.
- Verify `gpg.program` and `gpg.format` is unset.
- If `user.signingKey` is set, check if it's correct.
- Or just compare the output of `git config --list` of the two repos.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have already set my `user.name` and `user.email` globally and the commit to my hosted repositories is happening very fine but not other's hosted repositories.

Comment: I have checked as you said, the local configs are also same as the given in the secret key.

Comment: Yes, even I am using git bash in my windows OS

Comment: No, I only tried with the GnuPG to sign the commits.

Comment: the program is set. I have update my question with my .gitconfig setup.

Comment: I tried pushing commits by unsetting the gpg.program. But no use. Still getting the same error

Comment: Yes, I mistook using the words. But I am getting the error during committing the changes.

Comment: I did not find any core.signingkey. But there is a user.signinkey. And there is no local .gitconfig also. I am using global settings in every repo.

Comment: Sorry, it's `user.signingKey`. You need to use `git config` to query the values to makes sure the global settings are not overridden.

Comment: Yes the global values are intact. They are not changed. Even now I am not able to sign the commits in my own repo

Comment: At least now it's consistent among all repos, or was it like that all along? When was the last time you tried to sign your own repo before the previous?

Comment: It happend because I unset the gpg.program configuration. Now I am able to sign the commits to my repo again

Comment: Thanks for all you help. I really appreciate you gave time into my problem

Comment: `[gpg]`
         `program = 'gpg'`

Comment: What's the output these commands: `which gpg`, `file $(which gpg)`, `gpg --version`, `git version`?