# git error: could not find identity matching specified user-id

Tags: git, github, gpg-signature

So I just spent forever following the git instructions on how to generate a gpg key and sign my commits so they will show up in on my account. Followed everything to the T and got to these final steps with no complications:

```
git config --global user.signingkey 70DA..(my key)
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
```

BUT, when I finally go to:

```
git add .
git commit -S -m "whatever message"
```

I'm getting these three errors:

```
could not find identity matching specified user-id: 70DA..(my key)
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I've seen the last two errors in other posts, but not the one about a specified user-id. Does anyone know how to fix this or know of some short cut to verify my commits? I feel like 2 hours is a stupid amount of time to spend on this and I'm mildly embarrassed.

Comment: How did you obtain the value you put in `user.signingkey`?

Comment: i followed: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-gpg-key 

and got it from the command $ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG

Comment: Is the email address used in `git config user.email` the same as the email address used when creating the GPG key?

Comment: Ah you're the best! It's a different email than the one that comes up when I enter that into my command line. However, it matches my email that's on my github account which I presume is my verified email? Do I need to redo the process with the email that comes up when I enter git config user.email or do you know of a quicker fix? Thanks so much!

Comment: You can change the email in git config if needed using `git config user.email <your-email-here>`.

Comment: Ok so I tried that, and now when I enter the command to check the config email I just get an "=" with nothing next to it. When I change it back to the previous email and check it returns the email... puzzled

Comment: Do you have this issue resolved? I faced this issue and have made sure that user.name and user.email is correct. But still i got this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the email address and user id in `.gitconfig` are the same as the ones in your gpg key, and ensure that `gpg.format` is unset. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60939372/13765314

Answer (score 0):

You must add your list of keys, example

```
$ smimesign --list-keys

$ smimesign --list-keys
         ID: 0ff455a2708394633e4bb2f88002e3cd80cbd76f
        S/N: a2dfa7e8c9c4d1616f1009c988bb70f
  Algorithm: SHA256-RSA
   Validity: 2017-11-22 00:00:00 +0000 UTC - 2020-11-22 12:00:00 +0000 UTC
     Issuer: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
    Subject: CN=Octocat,O=GitHub\, Inc.,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US
     Emails: octocat@github.com

$ git config --global user.signingkey 0ff455a2708394633e4bb2f88002e3cd80cbd76f

$ git config --local user.signingkey 0ff455a2708394633e4bb2f88002e3cd80cbd76f
```

this link https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key